# Jquery question. How to hit the keyboard for this to work

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

How to use 'toggleb1' when clicked 'b2'. Is it even possible? If yes, how?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.b1').click(function() {
    var toggleb1 = $('.b1').toggleClass('red');
    $('.b2').toggleClass('blue');
    $('.b3').toggleClass('yellow');
  });
  
  $('.b2').click(function() {
    $('.' + toggleb1)
  })
});
```

```css
.base {
  background-color: black;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.yellow {
  background-color: yellow
}

.yes1 {
  color: black;
}

.yes2 {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="base b1">b1</p>
<p class="base b2">b2</p>
<p class="base b3">b3</p>
```

Comment: `toggleB1` is firstly not in scope of the second click handler, and it's also a jQuery object so concatenating it to a string is only going to create problems. What are you actually trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a function for that purpose:

```js
function toggleb1() {
  $('.b1').toggleClass('red');
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.b1').click(function() {
    toggleb1();
    $('.b2').toggleClass('blue');
    $('.b3').toggleClass('yellow');
  });
  
  $('.b2').click(function() {
    toggleb1();
  })
});
```

```css
.base {
  background-color: black;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.yellow {
  background-color: yellow
}

.yes1 {
  color: black;
}

.yes2 {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="base b1">b1</p>
<p class="base b2">b2</p>
<p class="base b3">b3</p>
```

Comment: I know this way. I will try to ask one more time. I will try using an example.
var x = $('.b1').toggleClass('red'); $('.b2').toggleClass('red'); $('.b3').toggleClass('red');

"var x change all 'b' "

$('.b1').click(use 'var x');

 When 'b1' was clicked all 'b' change color.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help)

Comment: So you want something like $('.b1, .b2, .b3).toggleClass('red'); ?

Comment: Something like.
I wanna use var for it. Because wanna use this var in another function.
Is it even possible?)

Comment: It is not possible to use a variable for it because you can not call a variable. What you are looking for is a function. Just write a function where you toggle your classes and then you can call it from other functions

Comment: I've edited the snippet above

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Lol. Thank you, you are great))
I thought this should work through var.
Thanks.